# Are the Items out of the Achievement Item Cauldrons giftwrapable?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I know they are untradable, but can you giftwrap them, then trade them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giftwrapping used to trigger a glitch which made untradeable items tradable. This glitch has been patched, and those items are still tradable. Today, gift wrap is just used to give untradeable items like the [UHHHH](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Horseless_Headless_Horsemann's_Headtaker) to other player in a trade. Because it is patched, they CANNOT be tradable forever. The item will become a carefully wrapped gift upon use. this tool is then allowed to be traded, and the item will be dropped when the gift is opened.

But more to the point, items from the [cauldron](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Halloween_Goodie_Cauldron) can be gift wrapped. The cauldron itself however, cannot.

wiki link:[here](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Gift_Wrap)

Comment: Given how Halloween works this year, I wouldn't be surprised if they were eventually made tradable/marketable.

Comment: @Powerlord let's hope they don't make the seal mask tradable (I think that mask is really creepy).

Comment: I meant the new items in the current update.  Right now you can get at most 6, while in previous years it was dependent entirely on how many gifts you managed to grab on Halloween maps.  For that matter, I was thinking the seal mask could still be gotten, but now I'm not sure.

Comment: Having said that, I'm aware that you can get these items from the Halloween crate in the Mann Co. Store... which sets an interesting precedent since they are crates that you buy instead of buying keys to open random drop crates.

Comment: I just wanted to know if the items out of the Cauldrons could be giftwrapped so they could be transferred, thank you.

Comment: @Powerlord you can still get the seal mask, as they brought back the gift cauldron. I wonder if the year for the name changed?

Comment: @Someguy112161 It's a different cauldron, though.  This years cauldrons contain 3 random items, at least one of which is Haunted (and Strange?).  Edit: Oh, apparently it still drops for the first Halloween event a player participates in.

Comment: @Powerlord I found that out from my friend (who is new to tf2). I wish I could get on tf2 to open mine, but I am too busy with road trips and flights and stuff.